# Disambiguating a function with INSERT INTO "table" FROM "table" RETURNING "id" = "id"

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm having trouble disambiguating this particular postgres function that inserts on a FROM statement of the target table and returns the newly created unique id:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "copyEntry"(OUT "entryId" INTEGER, IN "copyEntryId" INTEGER) RETURNING VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "entries" ("data") SELECT "data" FROM "entries" WHERE "entryId" = "copyEntryId" RETURNING "entryId" INTO "entryId";
  --Other plpgsql code below 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

`"entryId" INTO "entryId"` is ambiguous and I can't seem to find a way to alias the insert table to remove ambiguity. I would like to keep the output parameter to "entryId"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I omitted the INTO, corrected.

Comment: Do not use parameter names that have the same name as your columns. Rename your parameter and everything is fine. You should also avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ambiguity is between the variable and the column. There are two ways of disambiguating variable names: prefixing them based on table and code block names, or renaming them to be unique.

In this case, the parameters are declared in the outermost code block of the function, which is named after the function. So the `"entryId"` parameter can be referenced as `"copyEntry"."entryId"`. Meanwhile, the column is from the table `entries`, so can be referenced as `entries."entryId"`.

It may however be more readable to name your variables so that they aren't ambiguous in the first place, perhaps using a prefixing convention, so that your parameter would be `"out_entryId"`.

Answer (score 1):

Name the parameters to the function so you can distinguish them from columns in the table.  This is a good programming practice.

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "copyEntry"(OUT "out_entryId" INTEGER, IN "in_copyEntryId" ) RETURNING VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "entries"
      SELECT "data"
      FROM "entries" e
      WHERE "entryId" = "in_copyentryid"
      RETURNING "entryId" ;
  --Other plpgsql code below 
END;
```

The `RETURNING` clause should return the value from the row being inserted -- which is presumably some sort of default or auto-incremented value.  As the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-insert.html) describes:

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return
>   value(s) based on each row actually inserted. This is primarily useful
>   for obtaining values that were supplied by defaults, such as a serial
>   sequence number. However, any expression using the table's columns is
>   allowed. The syntax of the RETURNING list is identical to that of the
>   output list of SELECT.

The problem with your code might be the issue that the parameter has the same name as the function.

Comment: This will return the ID I copied, not the newly inserted ID unless I'm mistaken?